# Regular expression, optional (opening) parenthesis but closing parenthesis should then be mandatory

Tags: javascript, php, regex

If I've created a regular expression wich allows users to make formulas in my application. The regular expression I have works fine, however I want users to make opening and closing parenthesis.

My current regular expression is:

```
(
    ^[(N|R)]:   //START WITH N: OR R:

    (?:
        (?:
            [-.0-9]+|BT|PT|PN|PR  //ALLOW 48.934, BT, PT, PN OR PR
        )
        (?:
            \+|\*|\-|\/ //ALLOW OPERATORS /,*,+ and -
        )
    )+ //REPEAT x TIMES

    (?:
        [-.0-9]+|BT|PT|PN|PR //MUST END WITH 48.934, BT, PT, PN OR PR
    )

    (?:
        :V //ADD MANDATORY :V
    )

    (?:
        [-.0-9]+ //CLOSE REGEX WITH NUMBER
    )
)
```

A few examples in which the regular expression currently works:

```
N:0.3*BT/PN*PR:V1
N:2000+PN/BT:V0.5
R:BT*PN-500:V2
```

I'd like the regular expression to work with `()` which it currently doesn't a few examples:

```
N:(2000+PN)/BT:V0.5
R:BT*(PN-500):V2
```

I've read about positive and negative lookahead, to create if / else structures but I can't seem to find the right logic for my needs.

Much appreciated if someone can guide me in the right direction.

P.S. I'm using the javascript regex engine.

Comment: Do you need nested parens too?

Comment: @gcampbell No, nested parens aren't necessary.

Comment: Are you using XRegExp?

Comment: @gcampbell No not at the moment but I'm willing to include it in the application. Can you tell me if this is the correct file for XRegExp? https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp/blob/master/xregexp-all.js

Comment: Yes that's the right file.

Comment: Check https://regex101.com/r/aK1jP7/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a modified version of your regex that allows for any number of matched (but not nested) parens (see on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jA1jV6/1)):

```
(?=
    [^()]*
    (\([^()]+\)[^()]*)*
    $
)

^[NR]:   //START WITH N: OR R:

(?:
    \(?(?:[-.0-9]+|BT|PT|PN|PR)\)? //ALLOW 48.934, BT, PT, PN OR PR
    [-+*\/]                        //ALLOW OPERATORS /,*,+ and -
    \(?(?:[-.0-9]+|BT|PT|PN|PR)\)? //ALLOW 48.934, BT, PT, PN OR PR
)+ //REPEAT x TIMES

(?:
    [-+*\/]                        //ALLOW OPERATORS /,*,+ and -
    (?:[-.0-9]+|BT|PT|PN|PR)       //ALLOW 48.934, BT, PT, PN OR PR
    \)?
)*`


:V //ADD MANDATORY :V
[-.0-9]+ //CLOSE REGEX WITH NUMBER
```

Explanation:

Other than some clean-up of `[(N|R)]` and other extraneous groupings, the main change is to add a positive lookahead at the very beginning to ensure that any parens are found in pairs:

```
(?=
    [^()]*
    (\([^()]+\)[^()]*)*
    $
)
```

Then parens are allowed around each number or variable.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should change the second line of your RegEx `^[NR]:`, because almost every character between `[` and `]` is literal. That also counts for parenthesis.

Then I will need to disappoint you, there are conditionals using lookaheads, but not in JavaScript as I read. I do not know about XRegExp, maybe we just hope it can do that. The if-else should be something like:

```
(?(?=\()[^)]*))
```

Base Syntax:

```
(?(?=RegExp)then|else)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a regex like this:

```
/^[NR]:(([()0-9.-]+|BT|P[TNR])[*+/-]?)+:V[0-9.-]+$/
```

**[[`JavaScript Regex Demo`]](https://regex101.com/r/kS2kD1/1)**

In `PCRE` version it should be:

```
/^[NR]:(([()0-9\.-]+|BT|P[TNR])[*+\/-]?)+:V[0-9\.-]+$/
```

Notes:
`[]` is for match a single character present in its, so `[NR]` will match `N` or `R`, and `PT|PN|PR` can be `P[TNR]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use  parenthesis directly, as it is already meaning something to regular expression. So when you are using  parenthesis `'('` use `'\('` instead.